# Removing columns which has only "nan" values from a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a `NumPy` matrix like the one below:

```
[[182 93 107 ..., nan nan -1]
 [182 93 107 ..., nan nan -1]
 [182 93 110 ..., nan nan -1]
 ..., 
 [188 95 112 ..., nan nan -1]
 [188 97 115 ..., nan nan -1]
 [188 95 112 ..., nan nan -1]]
```

I want to remove the columns which only involve `nan` values from the above matrix.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your array is of `float`s now, you can identify all the columns which are NaN and use fancy indexing to retrieve the others:

```
d
array([[ 182.,   93.,  107.,   nan,   nan,   -1.],
       [ 182.,   93.,  107.,    4.,   nan,   -1.],
       [ 182.,   93.,  110.,   nan,   nan,   -1.],
       [ 188.,   95.,  112.,   nan,   nan,   -1.],
       [ 188.,   97.,  115.,   nan,   nan,   -1.],
       [ 188.,   95.,  112.,   nan,   nan,   -1.]])


d[:,~np.all(np.isnan(d), axis=0)]

array([[ 182.,   93.,  107.,   nan,   -1.],
       [ 182.,   93.,  107.,    4.,   -1.],
       [ 182.,   93.,  110.,   nan,   -1.],
       [ 188.,   95.,  112.,   nan,   -1.],
       [ 188.,   97.,  115.,   nan,   -1.],
       [ 188.,   95.,  112.,   nan,   -1.]])
```

Comment: Thank you, I have deleted my upper comment :)