# Dropnans from a list of numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, nan

I want to drop rows and columns which have all nan values on it from several numpy arrays.
This is my code to do it when I have just one array with shape(101,101):

```
    array=array[:,~np.all(np.isnan(array), axis=0)] 
    array=array[~np.all(np.isnan(array), axis=1),:]
```

My first attempt was to create a for loop with a list of arrays:

```
    my_list=[array1,array2,array3,array4,array5]

    for array in my_list:
       array=array[:,~np.all(np.isnan(array), axis=0)]
       array=array[~np.all(np.isnan(array), axis=1),:]
```

but it is not working at all. Any ideas?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing columns which has only "nan" values from a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154381/removing-columns-which-has-only-nan-values-from-a-numpy-array)

Comment: Do you save your `array` somewhere after you drop the np.nan values? And it always helps to make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```
my_list = [array1,array2,array3,array4,array5]
my_list = my_list[~np.isnan(my_list)]
```

Comment: An error occurred with this solution: "TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"

Comment: @GonzaloVelardeRodriquez check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657223/typeerror-ufunc-isnan-not-supported-for-the-input-types-and-the-inputs-could....I think you have to check the data types

Answer (score 0):

I find this eventual answer:

```
 my_list=[array1,array2,array3,array4,array5]
 my_new_list=[]
 for arr in my_list:
    rows_nan=np.where(np.isnan(arr).all(axis=0))
    new_arr=np.delete(arr,rows_nan,axis=0)
    cols_nan=np.where(np.isnan(arr).all(axis=1))
    new_arr=np.delete(new_arr,cols_nan,axis=1)
    my_new_list.append(new_arr)

array1,array2,array3,array4,array5=my_new_list
```